# sort by date java basic list

Tags: java, list, date, sorting

I have a list in java that contains lines of string id;city;date;days;price;vehicle. I need to sort all of it by date.(it's from a csv file that I read)
My list:

```
List <Ticket> list = new LinkedList<Ticket>();
```

And the way it is defined:

```
class Ticket {
  int id;
  String city;
  String date;
  int days;
  float price;
  String vehicle;

Ticket(int i, String c, String y, int d, float p, String v) {
    id = i;
    city = c;
    date = y;
    days = d;
    price = p;
    vehicle = v;
}
```

I was trying bubble sort but I have no clue how to compare dates and all the examples I found had ArrayList or were comparing small amounts of dates. I'm sorry if this is a bad question I just don't know how to apply everything I found to my situation.

Comment: You've defined `date` as a `String`. That will 100% work, **if** your `date` is stored in iso8601. Unfortunately, you haven't shared that information with us. Also, can you use the built-in sorting functionality?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes I can use built-in functionality. And I'm sorry but I have no clue what's iso8601. but I guess my date isn't sorted like that it's always string and the input for it is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Use LocalDate as sugested bellow and name your constructor variables normally not i,c,y,d... When you use the class in you IDE it provides you documentation if you name the parameters with descriptive names. One letter parameters is bad habbit... 
ISO 8601 date : 2004-02-09 String Sorting will work but if you use a different locale it gets messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Comparator interface. I prefer to convert the string into date first.

For dd/MM/yyyy (01/01/1970) pattern example (without conversion):

```
List<Ticket> list = new LinkedList<Ticket>();
... //fill the list.
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Ticket>() {
        public int compare(Ticket t1, Ticket t2) {
            String[] dateParts1 = t1.date.split("/");
            String[] dateParts2 = t2.date.split("/");
            
            int yearResult = dateParts1[2].compareTo(dateParts2[2]);
            if (yearResult != 0) {
                return yearResult;
            }
            
            int monthResult = dateParts1[1].compareTo(dateParts2[1]);
            if (monthResult != 0) {
                return monthResult;
            }
            
            int dayResult = dateParts1[0].compareTo(dateParts2[0]);
            if (dayResult != 0) {
                return dayResult;
            }
            
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

or (with conversion):

```
List<Ticket> list = new LinkedList<Ticket>();
... //fill the list.
Collections.sort(list2, new Comparator<Ticket>() {
        public int compare(Ticket t1, Ticket t2) {
            String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            try {
                Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(t1.date);
                Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(t2.date);
                return date1.compareTo(date2);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Also, you can do same thing in class with Comparable interface.

```
public class Ticket **implements Comparable<Ticket>** {

int id;
String city;
String date;
int days;
float price;
String vehicle;

Ticket(int i, String c, String y, int d, float p, String v) {
    id = i;
    city = c;
    date = y;
    days = d;
    price = p;
    vehicle = v;
}

**@Override
public int compareTo(Ticket o) {
    String[] dateParts1 = this.date.split("/");
    String[] dateParts2 = o.date.split("/");
    int yearResult = dateParts1[2].compareTo(dateParts2[2]);
    if (yearResult != 0) {
        return yearResult;
    }
    int monthResult = dateParts1[1].compareTo(dateParts2[1]);
    if (monthResult != 0) {
        return monthResult;
    }
    int dayResult = dateParts1[0].compareTo(dateParts2[0]);
    if (dayResult != 0) {
        return dayResult;
    }
    return 0;
}**
}
```

Then:

```
List<Ticket> list = new LinkedList<Ticket>();
... //fill the list.
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the date `String` to a date object like `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` and etc' (depending on your use case).

I randomly picked `LocalDateTime` for this example.

Then you can do:

```
tickets.add(new Ticket(1, "dsa", LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(5), 6, 5, "rew"));
tickets.add(new Ticket(0, "dsa", LocalDateTime.now(), 6, 5, "rew"));

List<Ticket> sortedTicketsByDate = tickets.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.date)) // comparing by date
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(sortedTicketsByDate);
```

Output:

```
 [
  Ticket(id=0, city=dsa, date=2021-05-02T23:46:03.214, days=6, price=5.0, vehicle=rew),
  Ticket(id=1, city=dsa, date=2021-05-02T23:46:08.197, days=6, price=5.0, vehicle=rew)
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another clean version using java records (new since JDK 16) which is recommended for plain java objects (pojos) that store data.

Read more info in this article : https://www.baeldung.com/java-record-keyword

You implement the Comparable interface based on date and `Collections.Sort()` can sort your ArrayList based on that.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


record Ticket(int id,String city,String date,int days,float price,String vehicle) implements Comparable<Ticket>{

    public int compareTo(Ticket ticket){

        return this.date.compareTo(ticket.date);
    }
}

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        Ticket ticket1 = new Ticket(1,"New York","2021-05-03",10,110.30f,"Ferrari");
        Ticket ticket2 = new Ticket(2,"Miami","2021-05-02",9,120.50f,"Porche");
        Ticket ticket3 = new Ticket(3,"Los Angeles","2021-05-01",10,150.50f,"Mercedes");
        
        var list = new ArrayList<Ticket>();

        list.add(ticket1);
        list.add(ticket2);
        list.add(ticket3);

        System.out.println("The List before sorting:\n");
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
        Collections.sort(list);
   
        System.out.println("\nThe List After sorting:\n");
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
       
    }
}
```